# How to use schema from one of the columns of a dataset to parse another column and create a flattened dataset using Spark Streaming 2.2.0?

Tags: apache-spark

How to use schema from one of the columns of a dataset to parse another column and create a flattened dataset using Spark Streaming 2.2.0?

I have the following **source data frame** that I create from reading messages from Kafka

```
col1: string
col2: json string


      col1    |   col2 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   schemaUri1 | "{"name": "foo", "zipcode": 11111}"
   schemaUri2 | "{"name": "bar", "zipcode": 11112, "id": 1234}"
   schemaUri1 | "{"name": "foobar", "zipcode": 11113}"
   schemaUri2 | "{"name": "barfoo", "zipcode": 11114, "id": 1235, "interest": "reading"}"
```

**My target data frame**

```
name   | zipcode | id  | interest
-------------------------------- 
foo    | 11111  | null | null
bar    | 11112  | 1234 | null
foobar | 11113  | null | null
barfoo | 11114  | 1235 | reading
```

**Assume you have the following function**

// This function returns a StructType that represents a schema for a given schemaUri

```
public StructType getSchema(String schemaUri)
```

Answer (score 1):

Schema column does not matter (and cannot be used with Spark API anyway) for the problem. All that is relevant is the columns you want to extract:

```
val names = Seq("name", "zipcode", "id", "interest")

df.select(names.map(s => get_json_object($"col2", s"$$.${s}") as s): _*)
```

or:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val superSchema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("name", StringType),
  StructField("zipcode", IntegerType),
  StructField("id", LongType),
  StructField("interest", StringType)
))

df.select(from_json($"col2", superSchema).alias("_")).select($"_.*")
```

Comment: If I ca't use col1 to extract col2 then I might have problem because I dont know the schema ahead of the time. the schemaid comes as part of the message but not the entire schema so I am not sure how i can construct something similar to `names` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example of ill-defined question. In the holiday spirit, let's ignore [lack of attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and focus on actual problems:

- Structured Streaming is, well... structured. It means it requires a well defined schema. For this reason it for example [disables schema inference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#schema-inference-and-partition-of-streaming-dataframesdatasets).
- Schema provided as a field reference is useless:

  - It cannot be used with existing API (form example `from_json` can only use string literal).
  - If it could be used, it is not possible to propagate this information back to the planner.
  - Finally it is obsolete - `JSON` itself is self describing and doesn't require schema for parsing. The reason why Spark functions need this information, is because planner requires it to compute execution plan, before query has been started.

Even if you could parse the data another problem is introduced by [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951036/how-to-use-schema-from-one-of-the-columns-of-a-dataset-to-parse-another-column-a#comment82883298_47956939):

> I might have problem because I dont know the schema ahead of the time

If you don't know the schema, then there is very little you can do with the resulting dataset. At the end of the day you're not better with the parsed data, than you'd be with JSON BLOB.

No comes real question - what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? This is once again missing from the question, but we can suspect on of two scenarios:

- You have a stream of unrelated data (unlikely). Possible solution here is to write data to separate Kafka topic to demultiplex

  ```
  stream.select($"col1" as "topic", $"col2" as "value").writeStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", ...)
    .start()
  ```

  and create separate input stream for each topic, with already known schema.
- Schema evolution. In that case define API for retrieving latest known schema.

  - If all variants are compatible, use it to parse data as already [shown in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47956939).
  - Otherwise redefine `getSchema` to return transformation function to the latest known schema.

  Keep schema constant across the lifetime of the query, if you want to upgrade - dispose old query and create a new one.

Comment: I am not sure why you say my question is "ill-defined". I had listed my source dataframe and I had listed my target dataframe..the question is simply how to get from source to target dataframe..It's not like I am asking I have a json string I want to know how to parse/flatten it into a dataframe. It sounds to me that my schemUri column is useless but then I am not seeing how people deal with Avro messages especially when one passes messages with a schemaUri as a reference but not the schema itself?

Comment: (This basically means you would know schema only when you get the value for schemaUri and use that to fetch to schema).